# Cordova resizes content

Tags: html, css, cordova

I'm making android webview application and I need to display vertical video from youtube on full html page (video is 360x640). For example my phone is 9:16 (720x1280). I'd like to get this: [IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KjUY9.png)

So video will be cut, but fit properly, but now I get this:
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zRB0A.png)

To do that I tried use this: `<meta name="viewport" content="width=360,height=640, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`
It also can be a problem with video iframe. My current code is:
HTML:

```
<div class="video-background">
<div class="video-foreground">
  <div id=player></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body, html {
   height: 100%;
   margin: 0;
}
html {
   min-width: 100%;
   min-height: 100%;
}
.video-background {
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; left: 0;
  z-index: -99;
}
.video-foreground {
  width: 360px;
  height: 640px;
}
.video-foreground,
.video-background iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

I rely on your help. Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution is pretty simple. Add this into CSS:

```
@media (min-aspect-ratio: 9/16) {
  .video-foreground { height: 300%; top: -100%; }
}
@media (max-aspect-ratio: 9/16) {
  .video-foreground { width: 300%; left: -100%; }
}
```